# Express problem with router readning head.html and tail.html files

Tags: javascript, html, css, express, router

I'm a student and we are staring with Express and I have a little question.

In my **routes/index.js** file I have this:

```
router.post('/orders.html', function(req, res, next) {
    var fhead = __dirname+ "/../views/head.html";
    var head = fs.readFileSync(fhead, 'utf-8');

    var ftail = __dirname+ "/../views/tail.html";
    var tail = fs.readFileSync(ftail, 'utf-8'); 

    //Do I need to add this???
    //res.render('index', function (err, html) {
    //  if(err) throw err; }

    var item = req.body.item;
    var quantity = req.body.quanty;
    var name = req.body.name;

    var rep = item + " was ordered " + quantity + 
    " times by " + name;

    res.send(head + rep + tail);
});
```

When I open my post orders.html the CSS is not okay and I don't understand why? It has everything it's supposed to have but the CSS.

But, when I open my head.html or tail.html file everything works perfectly!

**head.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>TITLE</title>
<link rel="stlesheet" style="text/css" href="bs/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="../public/css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="index.html" target="_self"> 
        <img src="../public/images/logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
        <h1 id="titre">SHOP</h1>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            Nav bar
            <ul class="horizontalbar">
                <li onclick="popup()">Me</li>
                <li><a href="contact.html" target="_self">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="orders.html" target="_self">Orders</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Wellecome!</h1>
        <p1>babla</p1>
```

**tail.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="../public/css/tail.css">
<div class="foot">
  <span>textext</span>
  <a href = "mailto: mail@com">Me</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you guys help me, why it doesn't work?

I have a question too, normally is it better to make my *index*, *orders*, *contact* html files with ALL the code, or only the body? If it only has the body I can call head + THE PAGE + tail and I repeat less code, is it a good way to work? Or it is better to write everything?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You will need an endpoint that serves the CSS file, or use a static directory.
The following code when configuring the app will set a directory which will be served statically.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

This will tell Express to serve everything in the '/public' directory as static content.

Now the request will render the missing css.

Comment: Hello!
I already have that line in my app.js file :O

Comment: can you show me the full code. and plus it is much better to use path to minimize the issue related with various path usage within the app

Comment: Hey! https://github.com/PedroLuisBernardos/code this is where we are at
The problem is in routes/index when we call post commandes (orders) it doesn't keep the CSS

Comment: Finally i got the solution , Just change `href="../public/css/style.css"` with `href="../css/style.css"` in both head and tail html file. after the post request the directory was not accessible  as the order file was in public aloof from views